# Is it possible to attach Google Cloud Persistent Disk to a Job in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I searched the documents. I wrote a job descripiton and deployed it but the disk did not show up in Kubernetes Dashboard.

Is it possible to attach Google Cloud Persistent Disk to a Job in Kubernetes?

Update: Here is the definition file. The disk `site1-disk` exists:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: page-retriever
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: page-retriever
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: page-retriever
        image: eu.gcr.io/crawler-162906/page-retriever:v1
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      volumes:
          - name: page-retriver-first-persistent-storage
            gcePersistentDisk:
              # This disk must already exist.
              pdName: site1-disk
              fsType: ext4
```

Comment: It's possible. Please post your definition so we can help you spot the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can. It looks like you're just missing the volumeMounts section of your container def:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: page-retriever
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: page-retriever
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: page-retriever
        image: eu.gcr.io/crawler-162906/page-retriever:v1
        volumeMounts:
        - name: page-retriver-first-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /path/to/where/the/disk/will/be/mounted/in/container

      restartPolicy: OnFailure

      volumes:
          - name: page-retriver-first-persistent-storage
            gcePersistentDisk:
              # This disk must already exist.
              pdName: site1-disk
              fsType: ext4
```

without that, the volume 'page-retrier-first-persistent-storage' has no relationship to the container 'page-retriever'